# How can I preprocess PDF files to text to optimize string search speed and minimize json data flow?

Tags: node.js, performance, pdf, vue.js

I'm implementing a search engine with vue-fuse , I have a requirement for **searching in pdf** files of some user created articles that could contain such files , **I solved it by preprocessing pdf to text on upload and appending a copy of the text to the article object in my db and searching through that** ( I'm using an npm package named pdf-textstring ).

Works like a charm but **i saw a significant increase in the json size I get from the server now , since there sometimes are rather big pdf files**. What could be done to improve my solution? Since performance is a big issue for this project any ideas , code snippets are welcome .

This is the data structure I'm using in my db for user uploads.
The id and url fields are for getting the files from the API. I added the text field for preprocessing PDFs

```
  data: [{
      fileName: String,
      id:String,
      originalName:String,
      url:String,
      text:String
    }]
```

This is how I check if a user uploaded a pdf and add the text field as a response from a preprocessing route that changes pdf to a simple string:

```
  if (x[0].originalName.includes('.pdf')) {
          axios.get(API+'/preprocess/pdf/'+x[0].id).then(data => {
              x[0].text = data.data;
          })
        };
```

Increase in JSON file just after 1 pdf upload was 3x the original size.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read about how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Read the article and edited the post , hope it's clearer now.